# Drawing on bitmap with shared source

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawing, share, pixel

I create a new bitmap by extracting 200x200 square from the other. I think the source (bitmap pixels) are shared by these two. Now, when I draw a circle on the original image, there is one on the copy too. But when I do this the other way around - draw a circle on newly created one - there is no circle on the original. Why does this happen? I thought the source pixels were shared.

```
    private Bitmap testa(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        //Create a new bitmap.
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(200, 200, bmpData.Stride, bmp.PixelFormat, bmpData.Scan0);

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        // Draw the new bitmap.
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) // or: newBitmap
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Red), 1, 1, 100, 100);
        }
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you actually 'share' pixels. You only copy them with or without the circle. Also: Why don't you copy with DrawImage? It has a format which does just that!

Comment: @TaW Then why when I copy the image first and draw on it later, the circle shows on both images? For DrawImage: it's just an example, I have only IntPtr to copy from not entire Bitmap.

Comment: Do we see the code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have used `LockBits()` and the `Bitmap()` constructor incorrectly, and so whatever behavior you see, it's purely academic and indeterminate.

The `IntPtr` that you pass to the `Bitmap(int, int, int, PixelFormat, IntPtr)` constructor is required to be one that you allocated for the purpose of that particular bitmap. You are required to ensure that [it remains valid for the lifetime of the `Bitmap` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx).

On the other hand, the `BitmapData.Scan0` pointer is guaranteed to remain valid only until you call `UnlockBits()`. At that point, it may or may not.

If you are curious, it might be interesting to try other experiments, like drawing on the original bitmap, viewing the new one, then drawing on the new bitmap, viewing the original, and then finally drawing on the original again and viewing the new one.

But whatever behavior you find in such an experiment, you cannot rely on it, because the behavior is not documented and not supported. As far as I know, there is no supported mechanism to allow two different `Bitmap` objects to share the same buffer. That it seems to work in some isolated case is pure luck.

Comment: I didn't read the remarks section from the linked page but my example is from there too. That explains so much. Thanks

Comment: What do you recommend for copying Bitmap from IntPtr? Should I create tmp Bitmap like this and then Clone() it?

Comment: Personally? I wouldn't mess with `LockBits()` at all unless you value speed _much_ more highly than convenience. To make an exact duplicate of the bitmap, just use the `Bitmap(Image)` constructor. If you want to crop the bitmap, create a new `Bitmap` object the size you want, call `Graphics.FromImage(Image)` passing the new bitmap, and then draw the part of the original bitmap that you want into the new bitmap, using the `Graphics.DrawImage()` method.

Comment: You can use `LockBits()` if you need the speed, but even there I would let GDI+ allocate the buffer for you. Create the empty new bitmap the size you want, call `LockBits()` on both original and new bitmaps, and then copy the bytes from one buffer to the other (e.g. with `Marshal.Copy()`).